# Display submenu multi menu level in php

Tags: php

I am trying to create multi menu level.
This is my code:

```
function multi_menu($parentid = 0, $i = 0, $trees = null) {
        $j = 0;
        $model = ClassRegistry::init('TypeBrief');
        $types = $model->find('all', array('conditions' => array( 'TypeBrief.parent_id' => $parentid)));
        if(!$trees)
        {
           $trees = array();
        }
        foreach ($types as $key => $type) {
            $trees[] = array( 'id' => $type['TypeBrief']['id'], 'name' => ++$i.$type['TypeBrief']['name']);
            $trees = $this->multi_menu($type['TypeBrief']['id'], $i.'.'.$j++, $trees);
        }
        return $trees;
   }
```

It display like:

```
1. Menu1

   1.1 Menu1.1

   1.1 Menu1.2

2. Menu2
```

But I want to display like:

```
1. Menu1

   1.1 Menu1.1

   1.2 Menu1.2

2. Menu2
```

I'm problem about Variable j. It does not increase up.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: (To make "code items" such as variable names (`j`) stand out in lines of text, use "backticks" (`).)

Comment: @Khanh.le  is this what you wanted click on this  [link](https://ibb.co/khXaaF) to see the result.  Tell me whether this is what you wanted or some thing more ..